# Validar ciertos carecteres especiales en un input

Tags: html, jquery

Necesito validar que en un input se puedan ingresar ciertos caracteres.

Implemente este codigo:

```
$('.limit').bind('keypress', function (event) {
            var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ._\-]+$");
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

El codigo funciona pero quiero agregar otros caracteres como @, !, *, $, &, % para que sean permitidos.

Los agregaba en `var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ._\-\@\$\!\*]+$");` pero me daba error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ibas mal encaminado con tu intento, pero no te hace falta **escapar** los símbolos que querías añadir, por lo que quitando el caracter de escape **\** de delante de cada caracter especial te valdría.

```js
$('.limit').bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ@!*$&%._\-]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="limit">
```

Comment: Gracias era exactamente eso